# Order rows where value begins with x before those that contains x

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this MySQL query:

```
SELECT
  id,
  title
FROM song
WHERE text IS NOT NULL
    AND title LIKE "%foo%"
ORDER BY title
```

What is a good way to adjust the ordering here so that those rows that *starts with* `foo` always comes before those that just contains it?

In other words, I want those `LIKE "foo%"` to come before those `LIKE "%foo%"`, without duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like the following.  I tried it out in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e2aa/1) and it works.

```
SELECT
  id,
  title
FROM song
WHERE text IS NOT NULL
    AND title LIKE "%foo%"
ORDER BY CASE WHEN title LIKE "foo%" THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, title
```